# R Markdown: my code runs on the console, but not when I try to knit to HTML

Tags: r, knitr, dplyr, r-markdown

I am running the following code (referencing a data frame in my Global Environment):

```
schedule_sort_1 <- group_by(FileName, Date)  
schedule_table_1 <- summarize(schedule_sort_1, Run_Time_hrs = sum(as.numeric(Interval_s))/3600, Start_Time = Time[1], End_Time = Time[length(Time)], Mean_Outdoor_Temp = mean(Outside.Air.Temp))  
kable(schedule_table_1, digits = 3, align = "c")
```

When I test using the "Run Current Chunk" button, the table appears as expected; however, when I then try to knit the document, I get the following error:

```
Error in group_by_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), add=add) : object 'FileName' not found Calls: <Anonymous> ...withVisible -> eval -> eval -> group_by -> group_by_ Execution halted
```

Any tips would be appreciate...thx

Comment: Quick update: I finally remembered that, for some reason, this issue goes away when I restart RStudio; I also tried detaching and reattaching several key packages in various orders (plyr and dplyr in particular are very sequence sensitive). Its working now, but I still can't tell you exactly why.

Comment: I normally call plyr first and then dplyr. That helps with many masking of packages. To be on the safe side though, check the `conflicts()` in your environment. If you do so after loading both packages you will see summarise and summarize. Which can account for trouble in your second line. Specify the package to use: `dplyr::summarise()`.